# Can we actually suspend accounts excessive discussion?

Tags: bug, account-suspension, grammar

Yes, you read that right, but no, we cannot. Yet here it is:

[image: profile suspension banner]

> This account is temporarily suspended excessive discussion in comments.

I think the "due to" was skipped, and it should read "*this account is temporarily suspended due to excessive discussion in comments*".

Can this be fixed?

Comment: The text after "temporarily suspended" is free-form because there are multiple possible tenses (e.g., "for voting irregularities", "to cool down", "because of low-quality contributions", etc.). Generally, these are filled in automatically when a moderator chooses a specific template for the accompanying moderator message. However, from what I've seen, it's possible for mods to change this text, possibly by fudging the request that gets sent to the server.

Comment: Its one of the default reasons - so that's not really the reason it should be. There *was* a recent revamp of the mod message UI so I wonder if that's the reason.

Comment: The full version would detract from the message that we're trying to send to users: No discussion, not even enough words for grammar. See [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426782/6083675)

Comment: @Laurel The "full version" meaning the sentence including the words "due to"? You're kidding, I take it?